# WriterInterceptor on Jersey 1.18

Tags: java, rest, jersey

On Jersey 2 there is a class called `WriterInterceptor`. It allows me to manipulate the entity response the server is sending to the client.

Is it possible to make something similar in Jersey 1.18? The closest I get was the `ContainerResponseFilter`, but , unlikely `WriterInterceptor`, it changes the response before the `ContextResolver` is called.

I need something that changes the response after the `ContextResolver.getContext` is called.